# Adding a toolbar to wxWidgets is generating a strange result

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task, add a toolbar to an app. I tried the most simple thing I could come up with, but the result is kind of strange, and I was wondering if this is suppose to behave this way or if I'm missing something.

The code is below, note that I even tried to use a native image(commented), but the result was the same.

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/image.h>
// #include <wx/artprov.h>

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);


bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Simple test", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
    frame->Show( true );
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    // wxToolBar *toolbar = CreateToolBar();
    // toolbar->AddTool(1001, _("New"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap("wxART_NEW"));
    // toolbar->Realize();
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText(wxT("Start"));

    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    wxImage image(wxT("save.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    if (image.Ok())
    {
        wxToolBar *toolbar = CreateToolBar();
        toolbar->AddTool(1001, _("New"), image);
        toolbar->Realize();
    }
    else
    {
         SetStatusText(wxT("image not ok"));   
    }
}
```

The result is here, note that the icon is in the app bar instead in a separate toolbar.

[image]

Comment: wx version? OSX version? is `toolbar` sample works for you?

Comment: wxVersion is 3.1.5
macOs Monterrey 12.0.1 (21A559)
I haven't test the example yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how toolbars work in recent macOS versions and wxWidgets is all about using the native UI, so this is most definitely a feature and not a bug, as this is how the native apps look too -- just look at Finder, for example.